# Should I use Futures.immediateFailedFuture or throw an Exception directly?

Tags: java, guava

I need to throw an exception in a `AsyncFunction`. Guava provides `Futures.immediateFailedFuture` to do that, but I want to know which is better compared with throwing an exception directly?

```java
ListenableFuture<Void> someFuture;
ListenableFuture<Void> next = Futures.transformAsync(
  someFuture,
  r -> {
    // opt 1
    throw new Exception();
    
    // opt 2
    return Futures.immediateFailedFuture(new Exception());
  }
);
```

Answer (score 2):

[From the docs](https://guava.dev/releases/20.0/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/AsyncFunction.html)

> Throwing an exception from this method is equivalent to returning a
> failing Future.

They are functionally equivalent, so it's only a matter of opinion which is "better". One is clearly more concise than the other.